# The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter

Tags: java, android, android-activity

when I tried to run my application its show the error below

```
Error running Dashboard: The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Well you can solve it by showing us some of your code. Post also your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: How are you trying to "run your application"? Launch from the IDE? Tap application icon from HOME screen? We aren't mind readers, give us more data!

Comment: In this case, it has nothing to do with AndroidManifest but a separate setting in Android Studio and in effect Intellij Idea with the AS plugin.

Answer (score 175):

I changed the `Select Run/Debug Configuration` from my `MainActivity` to `App` and it started working. Select App configuration snapshot:

[image]

Comment: I have googled this relentlessly and all I see is one liners of config or buttons to click, but no explanation why or what this is. What is this actually doing and why isn't it some automatic thing?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.
This mechanism is a configuration setting for different Run/Debug configuration settings. Please note that the error messages (as usual in Android) is  directing you completely into the wrong direction.

Comment: I selected Run | Edit Configurations | Launch | Default Activity
This is where it is "Always" set. It some how got changed to "Specified Activity"

Comment: @red888, you were trying to run the activity itself, directly, but by selecting 'app' you are telling Android Studio to run the app.  This answer also fixed things for me.  I had accidentally changed that setting to my activity, by inadvertently selecting a right-click menu option. Perhaps yours was changed a different way.

Answer (score 58):

Double check your manifest, your first activity should have tag

```
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

inside of activity tag.

If that doesn't work, look for target build, which located in the left of run button (green-colored play button), it should be targeting "app" folder, not a particular activity. if it doesn't targeting "app", just click it and choose "app" from drop down list.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Had no idea this was what was causing the issue. Kudos. This helped a lot.

Comment: This, This helped me... by selecting app instead of Activity name.

Answer (score 26):

First check a Launch Activity is set in your '`manifest.xml`' file has:

```
<activity android:name=".{activityName}">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If this is set correctly, next check your run/debug configuration is set to '`App`',

[image]

If the 'App' configuration is missing - you will need to add it by first selecting 'Edit Confurations'

[image]

If you do not have a '`App`' configuration you will need to create one, else select you '`App`' configuration and skip the creating steps. Also if your configuration is corrupt you may need to delete it but first backup your project. To delete a corrupt configuration, select it by expanding the '`Android App`' node and chose the '`-`' button.

[image]

To create a new configuration, select the '`+`' button and select 'Android App'

[image]

If you have just created the configuration you will be presented with the following default name value of '`Unnamed`' and module will have the value '`<no module>`' then hit '`Apply`' and '`OK`'.

[image]

Set this the name to '`App`' and select '`app`' as the module.

[image]

Next select '`App`' as the run configuration and Run.

[image]

Thats it!

Comment: This worked for me! I was missing an <intent> tag because I started an empty project.

Answer (score 11):

just add intent-filter Tag inside your activity

for example ::

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activityName">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: This helped me though I just used this code : <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>  inside the new activity I created.  Make sure to place it between <activity   .... </activity>

Answer (score 10):

If you're trying to launch a specific activity instead of running the launcher one.
When you select that activity. the android studio might through this error,
Either you need to make it launcher activity, just like answered by few others.
or you need to add `android:exported="true"` inside your activity tag inside manifest. It allows any external tool to run your specific activity directly without making it a launcher activity

Answer (score 8):

Just Select App from dropdown menu with Run(green play icon). 
it will run the whole the App not the specific Activity. if it doesn't help try to use  in that activity in ManiFest.xml file. 
thankyou

Comment: this question seems to be posted a while back so posting now wouldn't get much attention.

Answer (score 5):

In manifest.xml, select activity which u wanna start e set this informations:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 2):

it's because you are trying to launch your app from an activity that is not launcher activity. try run it from launcher activity or change your current activity category to launcher in android Manifest.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes if you change the starting activity you have to click edit in the run dropdown play button and in app change the Launch Options Activity to the one you have set the LAUNCHER intent filter in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Check your manifest,Open the file with .xml extension and then all your activities are listed your first activity should have this code enclosed in its tags

```
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

or there is another way u can choose from configuration which is drop down list on the left side of run button choose from App from it 
Hope it will help!!