# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors in the Project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I have some issues while running the gradle or running the application. Following are the error popping up in the console.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

The Following are the details of my Manifest.xml file that I have used in the project. I have upgraded my Gradle that's why its showing error. Please go through the below files.

**Manifest.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.lenovo.skanda">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        tools:node="replace"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".OnBoardActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Registration">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PositivityFragment" />
        <activity android:name=".Stories">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Feedback">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Notification" />
        <activity android:name=".NewAnalysis" />
        <activity android:name=".SucideCauses" />
        <activity android:name=".newStoriesmain" />
        <activity android:name=".activity_newpostivity" />
        <activity android:name=".sendstories" />
        <activity android:name=".AdminMenu" />
        <activity android:name=".adminUpdate" />
        <activity android:name=".adminUpdateQuotes" />
        <activity android:name=".adminUpdateQuotesSend" />
        <activity android:name=".QuoteList" />
        <activity android:name=".adminUpdateStories" />
        <activity android:name=".adminUpdateStoriesSend" />
        <activity android:name=".adminUpdatePositive" />
        <activity android:name=".adminUpdatePositiveSend" />
        <activity android:name=".PositiveList" />
        <activity android:name=".StoryList" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the following are the details of the Logcat file of my project.

```
11-05 22:29:07.729 28184-28226/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11910
To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
11-05 22:29:07.730 28184-28226/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.nis.app
11-05 22:30:54.533 28685-28821/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 12848
11-05 22:30:54.534 28685-28821/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
11-05 22:38:28.444 29535-29550/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 13001
11-05 22:38:28.451 29535-29550/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app de.motain.iliga
11-05 22:38:29.098 29535-29550/? I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
```

Error in the console:

```
  Android resource linking failed
G:\Project\Ongoing and Done\Aviaitions\RU01_Android_SDK_2.4\Demo\Android Studio\Skanda\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\com\example\lenovo\skanda\R.java: error: invalid symbol name 'com.example.lenovo.skanda:id/null'.
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used initial lunching intent in many activity. This should be in one activity (Which activity will open first).
Remove this from all activity except for one activity.

```
<intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Suppose you need to open `OnBoardActivity` first then only this activity have this intent filter. From other activity, the intent filter will be removed.

```
<activity android:name=".OnBoardActivity">
        <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: But there is problem occuring in the .MainActivity

Comment: The activity must be exported or contain an intent filter

Comment: Which activity will open first? MainActivity or other activity? If MainActivity open first then only MainActivity will contain the intent-filter.

Comment: OnBoardActivity will be open first @Faysal

Comment: Then only OnBoardActivity contains the intent-filter.

Comment: Check this for solving the issue on main activity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508303/the-activity-must-be-exported-or-contain-an-intent-filter

Comment: Ok as i am removing the intent filter from the .MainActivity. In the console Error running 'MainActivity'. The activity must be exported or contain an intent filter.

Comment: Ok the link help me.. The error is remove but a new error is popping up

Comment: Android resource linking failed
G:\Project\Ongoing and Done\Aviaitions\RU01_Android_SDK_2.4\Demo\Android Studio\Skanda\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\com\example\lenovo\skanda\R.java: error: invalid symbol name 'com.example.lenovo.skanda:id/null'.

Comment: Remove build folder and run again.

Comment: how to remove the build folder

Comment: Simply delete the build folder.

Comment: In Project<App<Build
is that safe to delete it.

Comment: Would you please add full error message with your question.

Comment: Checkout your XML and check you have used an id but its undefined. Check and find the invalid id you have used in your xml.