# The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter error

Tags: android, android-intent

When I try to run the code I keep getting this error "The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter".

I have set the small drop down beside the green run button to "app" and I have also put an intent-filter in my activity in the manifest. But this doesn't help. Hopefully someone can help me.

The code below is of my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.brian.project">



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginSignupActivity.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginSignupActivity.SignupActivity"></activity>
    <!--<activity android:name="WeightActivity"></activity>-->

</application>

</manifest>
```

My MainActivity code:

```
package com.example.brian.project;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.brian.project.LoginSignupActivity.LoginActivity;
import com.example.brian.project.LoginSignupActivity.SignupActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button Login, Create_Account;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button Login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        Button Create_Account=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_create_account);

        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                openLoginActivity();
            }
        });

        Create_Account.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                openSignupActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openLoginActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openSignupActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please verify that the MainActivity file is there in the original folder/path.

Comment: Yes, it's in the original folder/path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508303/the-activity-must-be-exported-or-contain-an-intent-filter)

Comment: I looked at that answer but it doesn't seem to help. I have done to my code what it suggests but I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `android:exported="true"` in the `<activity>` tag:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I just tried this but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Could you edit your post and show the complete manifest code please?

Comment: This code is the complete manifest file or the content inside <manifest> tag?

Comment: Maybe it can be an Android Studio bug. You can try to click on File > Invalidate Caches / Restart and then, Invalidate and Restart

Comment: It doesn't seems to be a manifest problem. Did you try to invalidate caches as I said above?

Comment: Yes but got another error saying that my activity is not assignable to "android.app.activity". This is stopping me from seeing if my original error has been resolved

Comment: Please, provide your complete activity code. Invalidate caches doesn't cause problems. I think the problem is in your activity

Comment: MainActivity Code displayed

Comment: I really can't see any problem with your code. The only thing I can suggest for now is to click in Build > Clean Project. Don't worry, it can't cause any other problem on your code. Let me know if it'll work

Comment: I tried that too but still getting the error saying that my activity is not assignable to "android.app.activity".