# Start-up activity cannot be changed

Tags: android

I wish to change the start-up activity of my app from Main to Start.

This is the present code section in the Manifest, which starts the app up with activity Main. No problem.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="Input Page">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Stats"
        android:label="Match Report Page" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Settings"
        android:label="Settings Page" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Help"
        android:label="Help Page" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Start"
        android:label="Start Page" >

    </activity>
```

In order to start up the app with activity Start, I changed the location of the intent filter, as follows

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="Input Page">     
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Stats"
        android:label="Match Report Page" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Settings"
        android:label="Settings Page" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Help"
        android:label="Help Page" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Start"
        android:label="Start Page" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

However, Android Studio then throws a compile error; **error running 'MainActivity': the activity must be exported or contain an intent filter**.

Earlier I changed the name of 'MainActivity' to 'Main' (with Refractor) to see if that would help, but the error persisted, keeping referring to 'MainActivity' (though that activity doesn't even exist any longer).

Please advise.

Comment: pls check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41780556/8035209

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Start.java in the left pane of android studio and select run Start.java

Comment: That worked, but now the app name beneath the launcher icon on my phone has changed to the label of the Start activity. I solved that by changing that label to the name of the app. Hopefully, this will hold, also for other users.