# The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter - even though there's an intent filter

Tags: android

IDK why it's happening, there's an intent filter in there.
I think I'm missing a tiny problem, that another point of view can detect faster/
thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.caloriecalculator">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Login"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Register"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: plz check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508303/the-activity-must-be-exported-or-contain-an-intent-filter

Comment: already saw it, and tried everything :(