# Activity doesn't launch in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am making an Android Studio project. In that I have made a button which when clicked opens an activity. But that activity doesn't open. When I tried to debug it, it shows this message:

> Error Running Note2Activity. The activity must be exported or contain an import-filter

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508303/the-activity-must-be-exported-or-contain-an-intent-filter)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your new custom activity to the `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
<activity android:label="your_label" android:name="name_of_custom_activity" android:launchMode="your_launchmode"/>
```

Comment: What launchMode should I set if I want to open that activity on a button click?

Comment: This article quickly gives you all the relevant information https://medium.com/android-news/android-activity-launch-mode-e0df1aa72242 It doesn't matter for your issue though.